# Resque queue and priority on Jobs

Tags: ruby, backgroundworker, resque

I am building a ruby app to upload a batch of files to the database. DelayJob is used currently and we want to move out of DJ. I have used Resque is the past.

In Resque can I set in what order to pick a job. I need a replace of what 'priority' is in DJ. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the solution for DJ ? Why to want to move out of from DJ?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/resque/resque

> Queue Priority
>
> Queues are picked off in order of their priority. A job from a lower
>   priority queue will only be picked off if there are no jobs for a
>   higher priority queue available.
>
> See Resque::WorkerQueueList#search_order for more details.